# Low framerate on XPS 7590

Tags: 18.04, gpu, framerate

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 on my XPS 7590. Everything went fine (at least after a fiddling about with the wifi driver), except for everything seeming very low framerate. 
I tried installing the driver for the GTX1650, but that did not help. In fact, it seems somewhat worse.
Nothing feels smooth when it moves across the screen, even though it really should be.
I googled for stuff but non of the fixes listed, actually worked.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do about this?

Comment: Which driver version, and how is it installed?

Comment: 430 and I tried doing it from the software ui (I can't think of the exact name, but it was om the "additional drivers" tab) and I tried doing it by running sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430

Comment: Well, did it work, or did you get errors?  Have you tried to open `nvidia-settings` to make sure the driver is in use?

Comment: Oh my bad, it did actually work and I can open the Nvidia X Server settings but like I said in the post, it did not help at all.